# Use function also as method and implement it only once

Tags: function, rust, methods

I am writting a library in which I will need to provide a lot of functions or methods to provide operations. For example, one of the operations is to compute the cosine on a given value. So I would write something like this:

```rust
fn cos<T>(value: &MyValue<T>) -> MyValue<T> {
    todo!()
}
```

Then, I can just call it like `let result = cos(&my_value)`.

Is there a way, or best practice so that I could also offer an API like `let result = my_value.cos()` without having to write the the `cos` function twice? I've been thinking about creating my own macro to do it, but I was wondering if there's another library providing this feature or if there's just a better way to do this.

Comment: Why not create it as a method only?

Comment: It probably _should_ be a method of `MyValue`. You can always call it like `MyValue::cos(&my_value)` if you really want to.

Comment: Also note that this is consistent with the way the standard library provides math functions.

Comment: you could make it a trait and have the default implementation

Comment: I would probably do this as a trait, since it seems you want it to be a function that takes that type and returns that type: IE, you can apply it to multiple types. If the `cos` function is consistent in behavior for all types, a trait would be the correct way to go IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling the function within the method implementation like so:

```rust
fn cos<T>(val: &MyValue<T>) -> MyValue<T> {
    // snip
}

struct MyValue<T> {
    // snip
}

impl<T> MyValue<T> {
    fn cos(&self) -> Self {
        cos(self)
    }
}
```

That being said, I'm not sure exactly why you would want to - as others have pointed out the standard library only provides methods in situations such as this. This could be seen as a violation of the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but now crate [as-method](https://docs.rs/as-method/0.1.0/as_method/) can do it.